# Reorder images using jquery

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have 4 small thumbnail images sitting side by side which when clicked upon each change a small div/panel underneath them to show different text.

When the image is clicked I want them to reorder by the one that was clicked to go to the far left. So if 2 was clicked below:

1 2 3 4

It should become

2 1 3 4

Ideally sliding, i found lots of Jquery UI plugins to show sliding carasols etc but none to reorder images, any know of any?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for (*no sliding as noticed by **neal***).

```
$('img-selector').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

colorful demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Lu5Q8/

Comment: @neal, indeed .. its not the *ideal* solution as requested. But it fits the rest of the requirements, so here it is as an option and learning experience :)

Answer (score 5):

Here you go. :D

http://jsfiddle.net/rNzf7/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = 100;
    $('img').each(function() {
        $(this).css("left",x+"px");
        $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(0,90,"+x+")");
        x += 55;
    });
});

$('img').click(function(e) {
    
 
    $(e.target).animate({
        left: "100"
    });
    
    $(e.target).siblings().each(function (){
        if ( $(this).position().left < $(e.target).position().left ) {
            $(this).animate({ left: "+=55" });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: bring the relevant code over here, and you will get my vote ;) *the point is to show the answer here as well*

Answer (score 1):

Why not reorder them by drag and drop using Jquery UI Sortable > http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid

Comment: Hi Morgar, thanks for the reply, problem is I want it to happen automatically so on click they order by themselves rather than with user drag/drop.

Comment: I understand. You should be able to do it with a few lines of jquery, by using `.animate()`